# Borland c++ 5.02 for win8 64bit

Tags: windows, 64-bit, borland-c++

I am to start c++ however I'm stalled in the first step
Mine is 64 bit but I can't find borland c++  for my version
Does it exist?
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Borland <sup>1</sup> C++ 5.02 is a legacy 32-bit IDE.  It can run on 64-bit Windows that have WOW64 installed, but it cannot produce 64-bit executables.

<sup>1. Borland is not in the developer tools business anymore, they sold their tools to Embarcadero years ago.</sup>

If you want an IDE that is a successor to Borland C++ 5.02, look at Embarcadero's [free Community Edition IDE](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/starter), or even just its updated [free C++ command-line compiler](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/ccompiler).

Or, there are plenty of other 3rd party C++ compilers available (Gcc, Clang, MinGW, Visual Studio community edition, etc).

Comment: Pretty sure it was a 32-bit compiler.  Released in 1997 so it had to be.  It was too buggy to be usable, no surprise they gave up on the product line.

Comment: Borland C++ 5.02 is a 32-bit ide and can (with few tweaks) still run under 64-bit Windows 10 - I am using occasionally when porting legacy OWL applications to OWLNext.

Comment: @Jogy thanks. And what would those "few tweaks" need to be?

Comment: There were some VBX components that were causing an error message when the 5.02 IDE was started, and the solution was to delete or rename them, they were found on one of the Window system folders. Can't recall the exact details, but other than that it works just fine.